# Should I call verifyBuyer for off-session payments

Tags: square-connect, square

I'm integrating Square payment gateway into our system. And want it to support SCA.

In their dev docs it says that I should call verifyBuyer each time I want to charge CoF. Also, **"If a challenge is required, Square automatically displays the challenge to the buyer"**. It's ok for on-session payments. But what about off-session payments, like cars rental service does - without customer online (automatically)?

In their dev docs it says nothing or I'm missing something.

Did anybody face with such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our docs state:

> Important
>   The SCA flow must not be initiated for a card on file transaction where the buyer is not present. In this scenario, do not call the verifyBuyer function. You can still charge the card but be prepared to handle the CARD_DECLINED_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED error.

Basically, don't call `verifyBuyer`, and don't pass a token to the payment endpoint. The payment could still technically fail, so you should build functionality to handle that.

https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/cookbook/verify-buyer-on-cof

Comment: yes, seems your docs is under update process yet. initially, it said to call verifyBuyer in both cases

Comment: Hey, @Vyacheslav, Can you please answer what approach can we use to handle SCA off-session payments?